# sort return data with SQL in SQLite order by row

Tags: sql, sqlite, sorting, row

I have a DB which has 8 columns, all are integers range 1~99:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4    Col5    Col6    Col7    Col8
1       13      24      18      35      7       50      88
13      4       33      90      78      42      26      57
22      18      30      3       57      90      71      8
```

...

When I perform "select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col5, Col6, Col7, Col8 from MyTable where Col4>10"
I would like the return data is sorted, e.g. the first row should return like this:

1,7,13,24,35,50,88

However, "order by" only work on "Column", is there anyway to preform this in SQL ? Or need a temp table/max() to perform this ? Thanks.

Regds

LAM Chi-fung

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current design is not appropriate for this requirement.
Consider changing it to something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE tablename (
  id INTEGER, -- corresponds to the rowid of your current table 
  col_id INTEGER NOT NULL, -- 1-8, corresponds to the number of each of the columns ColX 
  value INTEGER NOT NULL  -- corresponds to the value of each of the columns ColX  
);
```

You can populate it from your current table:

```
INSERT INTO tablename (id, col_id, value)
SELECT rowid, 1, Col1 FROM MyTable UNION ALL
SELECT rowid, 2, Col2 FROM MyTable UNION ALL
SELECT rowid, 3, Col3 FROM MyTable UNION ALL
SELECT rowid, 4, Col4 FROM MyTable UNION ALL
SELECT rowid, 5, Col5 FROM MyTable UNION ALL
SELECT rowid, 6, Col6 FROM MyTable UNION ALL
SELECT rowid, 7, Col7 FROM MyTable UNION ALL
SELECT rowid, 8, Col8 FROM MyTable
```

Now you can get the result that you want with `GROUP_CONCAT()` window function and aggregation:

```
SELECT result
FROM (
  SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(value) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY value) result
  FROM tablename
  WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM tablename WHERE col_id = 4 AND value > 10)
)
GROUP BY id
HAVING MAX(LENGTH(result))
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=da604b77b7f6ddc00ede2e0de5e0c1ee).
Results:

| result |
| --- |
| 1,7,13,18,24,35,50,88 |
| 4,13,26,33,42,57,78,90 |

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Data is feed from other process (other people), seems that I need to "rearrange" the table myself before I can perform this.

Comment: @Chi-fungLAM the code to create and populate the new table is in my answer. All you have to do is execute it.

Answer (score 0):

Fix your data model!  You should not be storing values in columns.  You should be storing them in rows.

That is, SQL doesn't "sort columns".  It deals with data in rows!

You can do what you want by unpivoting the data into rows, calculating the new order, and then reaggregating:

```
with t as (
      select row_number() over () as id,
             t.*
      from mytable t
      where col4 > 10
     )
select max(case when seqnum = 1 then col end) as col1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then col end) as col2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then col end) as col3,
       max(case when seqnum = 4 then col end) as col4,
       max(case when seqnum = 5 then col end) as col5,
       max(case when seqnum = 6 then col end) as col6,
       max(case when seqnum = 7 then col end) as col7,
       max(case when seqnum = 8 then col end) as col8
from (select row_number() over (partition by id order by col) as seqnum,
             x.*
      from (select id, col1 as col from t union all
            select id, col2 as col from t union all
            select id, col3 as col from t union all
            select id, col4 as col from t union all
            select id, col5 as col from t union all
            select id, col6 as col from t union all
            select id, col7 as col from t union all
            select id, col8 as col from t
           ) x
     ) x
group by id;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Data is feed from other process (other people), seems that I need to "rearrange" the table myself before I can perform this.